# python from sync import Sync giving script error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sync'

Tags: python, android-source, repo, dragonboard

I am attempting to do my own build of Android for the DragonBoard 410c using the materials from Qualcomm under Ubuntu 20. I have downloaded from the Qualcomm developer portal the file, `linux_android_board_support_package_vla.br_.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4.zip`, containing the materials which I have unzipped into a folder `~/Documents/linux_android_board_support_package_vla.br.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4` making the materials available include the shell script `DB410c_build.sh`.

The unpacking and setup is done by `DB410c_build.sh` which performs the various actions such as generating the `.repo` directory tree with the python files that are used by the shell script and downloading the source.

I have run into a number of syntax errors from the various python scripts, it appears this was written for python 2, that I have been able to address thus far. By the way, `python --version` reports `python 2.7.18` yet I still see errors indicating python 3 is being used.

The latest error comes from the python script, `.repo/repo/subcmds/smartsync.py` and when it executes, I get the following error that I have been unable to figure out or find a solution through searches.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rick/Documents/linux_android_board_support_package_vla.br.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4/APQ8016_410C_LA.BR.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0_6.0.1_Marsh_Mallo_P2/.repo/repo/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    from subcmds import all as all_commands
  File "/home/rick/Documents/linux_android_board_support_package_vla.br.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4/APQ8016_410C_LA.BR.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0_6.0.1_Marsh_Mallo_P2/.repo/repo/subcmds/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    mod = __import__(__name__,
  File "/home/rick/Documents/linux_android_board_support_package_vla.br.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4/APQ8016_410C_LA.BR.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0_6.0.1_Marsh_Mallo_P2/.repo/repo/subcmds/smartsync.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sync import Sync
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sync'
```

The complete python source file, `smartsync.py` is as follows:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

from sync import Sync

class Smartsync(Sync):
  common = True
  helpSummary = "Update working tree to the latest known good revision"
  helpUsage = """
%prog [<project>...]
"""
  helpDescription = """
The '%prog' command is a shortcut for sync -s.
"""

  def _Options(self, p):
    Sync._Options(self, p, show_smart=False)

  def Execute(self, opt, args):
    opt.smart_sync = True
    Sync.Execute(self, opt, args)
```

This just the latest issue with the python scripts from this file downloaded from https://developer.qualcomm.com/hardware/dragonboard-410c/software attempting to use

```
Android Board Support Package 
vLA.BR.1.2.7-01010-8x16.0-4
```

Most of the previous errors have been due to incorrect syntax with `except` and `raise` as well as `print` along with a couple of `import` errors that were easy to find solutions for (Thank you StackOverFlow!).

However I can't find anything about this one.

Comment: Something to investigate. There may be a file `subcmds/sync.py` which contains a `class Sync` and this may be a local python file and part of this package and not a standard python library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a syntax error in the file `smartsync.py` located in the folder `.repo/repo/subcmds` and the `from sync import Sync` statement in that file.

The `sync` is actually referencing the file `sync.py` which is also located in the folder `.repo/repo/subcmds` and not some python file external to this body of python source code.

The `from` statement was missing the directory specifier of `subcmds` where the file `sync.py` is located. The line of code should have been written `from subcmds.sync import Sync` in order to import the class `Sync` from the file `sync.py` located in the folder `subcmds`. I assume this is because the python script is being run with the current directory set to `.repo/repo` and not `.repo/repo/subcmds`.

After this change was made to the file, the script ran successfully until the next error in a different file which needed to be corrected.